# Google Calendar API is Support Windows phone platform?

Tags: api, windows-phone-7, google-calendar-api

I have been check out  Google Calendar API as fllow:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

but i'm not sure about it can be Support Windows phone Platform?

is there have any opensource project packup Google calendar API on windows phone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's supported because REST is enabled.

GTalkChat is an open source app that does the authentication part with Google APIs, perhaps you can start from there

[GTalkChat at GitHub](https://github.com/lhchavez/gtalkchat)

and [basics of REST for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/gg703400.aspx)

Comment: @kaichen please upvote and/or mark as answer if it is the answer you were looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

http://kelp.phate.org/2012/04/google-calendar-api-with-oauth-20.html.

this sample have function list about Google Calendar